# Can we assign the result of concatenation to a variable?

Tags: c

I wanted to know that can we assign the `strcat()` to another variable

I have tried it by `*str1` and `*str2` inside `strcat()` but same thing happened no output.

```
int main() {
    char *str1 = "united";
    char *str2 = "front";
    char *str3;
    str3 = strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str3);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it would print `united front` but blank screen came as output.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/malloc/malloc2.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is any built-in function already but you can achieve what you want with this kinda function.

```
    char* concatStrings(const char* s1, const char* s2)
    {
        char* outputString= malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
        outputString[0] = '\0';
        strcat(outputString, s1);
        strcat(outputString, s2);
        return outputString;
    }
```

**Edit:**

I did not feel the need to remind at first that after the returned string is done you should release allocated memory for the returned string with `free()`. Besides, to be able to call `free()` for allocated memory, output type shold be type of `char*`.

Comment: Why are you declaring the return type as `const char *`?

Comment: Your code effectively finds the length of the strings twice each. Once you know their length you can use `memcpy()`.

Comment: You should also test for memory allocation failure and gracefully return `NULL`, avoiding undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie This is already stores the returned array in a variable, so why create a char * variable to store returned value? Also, yes, free() operation should be performed after the returned variable is done.

Comment: @chqrlie You are rigth, I am updating my answer. Thank you for warning me.

Comment: @Hasan: OK, but also add a test `if (outputString != NULL) {` to avoid undefined behavior on memory allocation failure.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is:

> yes the return value of `strcat` can be assigned to a variable. It is always equal to its first argument, but it is sometimes handy to pass it directly to another function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[20];
    printf("%s\n", strcat(strcpy(buf, "Hello "), "world!"));
    return 0;
}
```

The long answer is:

Your code has undefined behavior because you pass a string constant `"united"` as the destination array of `strcat()`.  Attempting to modify string constants has undefined behavior.

You should modify your code this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[20];
    const char *str1 = "united";
    const char *str2 = "front";
    char *str3;

    strcpy(buf, str1);
    str3 = strcat(buf, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str3);
    return 0;
}
```

Since no space was appended, the output will be:

```
unitedfront
```

Comment: @Osiris: Absolutely correct! Yet another cut+paste bug failing to properly adjust the pasted code.